# XSL Stylesheet not displaying what I want in the final webpage

Tags: xml, xslt

I have tried a few different ways to display wName, wContact with no luck so I am looking to get help.

Here is my page

```
<delivery>
<wName>Reston</wName>
<wContact>John McAdams</wContact>
<orderDate>8/15/2005</orderDate>
<recvDate>8/21/2005</recvDate>
<recvBy>David Hanson</recvBy>
<sCost>385</sCost>
<manifest>
   <item itemID="CM204">
     <itemName>Camshaft (Box 20)</itemName>
     <itemQty>10</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>289.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="CR201">
     <itemName>Carburetor (Box 25)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>159.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="CRK310">
     <itemName>Crankshaft (Box 10)</itemName>
     <itemQty>3</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>109.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="DS503">
     <itemName>Distributor (Box 15)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>125.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="EC501">
     <itemName>Engine Computer (Box 1)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>414.59</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="OP460">
     <itemName>Oil Pump (Box 20)</itemName>
     <itemQty>3</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>214.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="SP300">
     <itemName>Standard Spark Plugs (Box 100)</itemName>
     <itemQty>10</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>114.45</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="SP310">
     <itemName>Delux Spark Plugs (Box 100)</itemName>
     <itemQty>10</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>139.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="TB261">
     <itemName>Timing Belt (Box 40)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>94.90</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="TR301">
     <itemName>Transmission (Box 1)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>310.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="BA105">
     <itemName>Standard Batteries (Box 12)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>495.40</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="BA205">
     <itemName>Security Batteries (Box 4)</itemName>
     <itemQty>3</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>289.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="BA115">
     <itemName>Delux Batteries (Box 12)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>525.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="SF305">
     <itemName>Standard Air Filters (Box 16)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>148.25</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="FI372">
     <itemName>Fuel Injection Kits (Box 1)</itemName>
     <itemQty>15</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>129.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="BRK681">
     <itemName>Brake Line Kit (Box 1)</itemName>
     <itemQty>25</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>29.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="CF401">
     <itemName>Cooling Fans (Box 20)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>34.41</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="ALT561">
     <itemName>Chrome-plated Alternators (Box 5)</itemName>
     <itemQty>3</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>105.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="ALT610">
     <itemName>Alternator Case Kit (Box 1)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>69.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="CC310">
     <itemName>Catalytic Converters (Box 5)</itemName>
     <itemQty>3</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>121.59</itemPrice>
  </item>
  <item itemID="CC315">
     <itemName>Universal Catalytic Converters (Box 5)</itemName>
     <itemQty>5</itemQty>
     <itemPrice>68.95</itemPrice>
  </item>
 </manifest>
 </delivery>
```

Here is the XSL style sheet

```
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"     
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Election Night Results</title>
 <link href="autotxt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 <ul>
 <xsl:for-each select="delivery/manifest/item">
 <xsl:for-each select="delivery/wName">
 <li>
 <xsl:value-of select="wName"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="itemName"/>
 </li>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </ul>
 </body>
 </html>
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You have opened two xsl:for-each elements and only closed one for a start.

Comment: is the delivery element the root element of your XML?

Comment: Yes it is. I thought I could just add another for-each and select the wName but its not working that way.

Comment: I just want it to display. I can format it later, I just cant get to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is fine. I have corrected some mistakes in your XSL. Try this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>Election Night Results</title>
<link href="autotxt.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<p><strong>wName:</strong><xsl:value-of select="/delivery/wName"/></p>
<p><strong>wContact:</strong><xsl:value-of select="/delivery/wContact"/></p>
<h2>Parts</h2>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="/delivery/manifest/item">
<tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="itemName"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="itemQty"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="itemPrice"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This line:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/delivery/wName"/>
```

Selects the wName element from within the delivery element which you indicated was the root element.

This line:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/delivery/manifest/item">
```

Tells the XSL interpreter to loop through each item element in /delivery/manifest

And this line:

```
<li><xsl:value-of select="itemName"/></li>
```

Outputs the text node within the ltemName element into a li html element. Because you're inside a foreach element which is selecting the /delivery/manufest/item elements you only have to provide the name of the element within the item element that you wish to output, in this case itemName.

This line tells the interpreter to stop looping:

```
</xsl:for-each>
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: But i've tried creating another for-each but with no luck. Can you give me an example of what you think it should look like.

Comment: it doesnt work. I've tried to get it to work with no joy. It returns the same thing as mine. I just get the list of parts.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide you with an example of how I would do this.

Comment: Thats alot more complicated than I thought it would be. I do applogize but I am still fairly new to this and need alot of hand holding.

Comment: That's OK. You can get a tutorial on XSLT here: http://w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp (w3schools.com is not run by the W3C)

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggests that you haven't understood the way context works in XSLT and XPath. When you use xsl:for-each, each node selected by the select expression becomes the context node for evaluating further path expressions within the loop.

So when you write this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="delivery/manifest/item">
 <xsl:for-each select="delivery/wName">
 <li>
 <xsl:value-of select="wName"/>
```

line 2 starts looking for a delivery element that is a child of the item element selected in the previous line, while line 4 starts looking for a wName element that is a child of the wName element selected in line 2. This is clearly not what you intend. Line 2 should probably start with "/delivery" to select from the root of the tree, while line 4 should use "select="." to select the context item rather than its child.